# Avoiding character encoding in Apache Abdera

Tags: java, atom-feed, apache-abdera

I'm working to write a simple article editor which will be used with a CMS system which offers an Atom API to add/edit articles. To communicate with the CMS, I am using the Apache Abdera library. But I'm running into a problem with character encoding. The data sent to the CMS will be encoded like this:

```xml
<entry>
  <content xmlns:vdf="http://www.vizrt.com/types" type="xml">
    <vdf:payload>
      <vdf:field name="body">
        <vdf:value>&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">&lt;p>Text comes here&lt;/p>&lt;/div></vdf:value>
      </vdf:field>
    </vdf:payload>
  </content>
</entry>
```

But the CMS system requires this:

```xml
<entry>
  <content xmlns:vdf="http://www.vizrt.com/types" type="xml">
    <vdf:payload>
      <vdf:field name="body">
        <vdf:value><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>Text comes here</p></div></vdf:value>
      </vdf:field>
    </vdf:payload>
  </content>
</entry>
```

In other words, no character escaping. Does anyone know how this can be achieved using Apache Abdera?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with abdera's internals and therefore can't explain exactly what is happening here, but I think the essence is that you can not use Strings or plain text as values if you don't want abdera to escape stuff. Instead, you must use an `Element` with abdera-type `XHtml`.

Something like this worked for me:

```
String body = "<p>Text comes here</p>"

//put the text into an XHtml-Element (more specificly an instance of Div)
//I "misuse" a Content object here, because Content offers type=XHtml. Maybe there are better ways.
Element el = abdera.getFactory().newContent(Content.Type.XHTML).setValue(body).getValueElement();

//now create your empty <vdf:value/> node.
QName valueQName = new QName("http://your-vdf-namespace", "value", "vdf");
ExtensibleElement bodyValue = new ExtensibleElementWrapper(abdera.getFactory(),valueQName);

//now attach the Div to that empty node. Not sure what's happening here internally, but this worked for me :)
bodyValue.addExtension(el);
```

Now, `bodyValue` can be used as value to your field and Abdera should render everything properly.